# Changing style of (sub)sections

Tags: sectioning, books, section-titles

How can I change the style of sections and subsections...

I want this:

[image]

Instead of this default style:

[image]

Please note that the first style is indented meanwhile the default one is not. My document class is `book`.

Comment: Please give us an MWE (minimal working example, i.e. a file that is reduced to the max while still compiling) to look at …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `titlesec` package and redefine the format for `\subsection` like

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\hspace*{\parindent}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.

Comment: I would also suggest putting the dot (and the space thereafter) in the format definition rather than the title itself. The last empty `{}` is for `after-code`, so such adjustments could be made there. This would guarantee consistency.